# PHP PDO: Search array value inside of MySQL's JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I got the following data in MySQL's JSON-type column:

```
{"2": [2, 3], "3": [29], "71": "test"}
```

I need to search array value inside of attribute "2", which works just fine when variables are placed inside the query, but not when using PHP's PDO arrays.

```
$field_id = 2; 
$option_id = 2;
$query = "SELECT id FROM notes WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '{\"$field_id\": $option_id }')";
try { 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $used_qty = $stmt->rowCount(); 
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    exit; 
}
// $used_qty returns 1 which is correct;
```

Binding through array returns 0:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM notes WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '?')";
try { 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(array('{"' . $field_id . '": ' . $option_id . '}"')); 
    $used_qty = $stmt->rowCount(); 
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    exit; 
}
```

Can't figure out what I missed here.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Alex. Stop amending your question as you get answers. It makes the answers look like nonsence and is no use to anyone else that may find your question and be looking for a similiar answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling PDO exceptions:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dsn_user, $dsn_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

I got clear error message saying that only value can be accepted as a second parameter:

> Query failed: SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3141 Invalid JSON
>   text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "The document root must
>   not follow by other values." at position 8.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains

But there is a third optional [path] parameter available: `JSON_CONTAINS(json_doc, val[, path])`

Which is exactly what I needed:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM notes WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, ?, ?)";
try { $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query); $stmt->execute(array($option_id, '$."' . $field_id . '"')); $used_qty = $stmt->rowCount(); } catch(PDOException $ex) { echo 'Query failed: ' . $ex->getMessage(); exit; }
```

Thanks to Marc B.

Answer (score 5):

You quoted your placeholder:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM notes WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '?')";
                                                         ^-^--
```

which means it's NOT a placeholder, it's a string containing a question mark.

Remove those quotes.

Comment: Did you enable exceptions in PDO? If not, the try/catch is useless. PDO defaults to "fail by returning boolean false".

Comment: I swear you answered a very similiar question about an hour ago. It must be the current coursework somewhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly: well, it is the start of the school year. it's never too early to start get others to do your homework/debugging for you...

Comment: I even remember unpacking the script on the other one in the same way as this. LOL

Comment: Sure enough: enabled exceptions and I get the following error referring to the `$stmt->execute(array('{"' . $field_id . '": ' . $option_id . '}"'));` i posted above...  Error message: `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMessage() on null in /usr/home/testproject/master/content/settings/settings-notes.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/home/testproject/master/index.php(78): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/usr/home/testproject/master/content/settings/settings-notes.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />`

Comment: wel,l that's because you have `PDOException $ex`, but are using `$e`. But still, you got an exception, therefore the query failed. But you can't get the message, because you're handling the exception wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely need vacation.... `Query failed: SQLSTATE[22032]: <<Unknown error>>: 3141 Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "The document root must not follow by other values." at position 8.`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains   you can only search for VALUES, not key:val pairs.

Comment: It does mention `[, path]` as a third optional parameter. Can I use something like `$."$field_id"` in path ?

Comment: probably yeah. honestly, though. I haven't used the 5.7 json functions before, so that's new territory for me.

Comment: Sure enough, this worked `JSON_CONTAINS(data, ?, ?)` with `$stmt->execute(array($option_id, '$."' . $field_id . '"'))`. Thanks for babysitting. =)